# Why some AWS IAM actions require all resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

when creating a IAM policy, if I choose ListAllMyBuckets, the resource become "*", rather than "arn:aws:s3:::*". I do not understand it. How can ListAllMyBuckets requires resources not in s3? Doesn't "Bucket" mean S3 bucket?

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since s3:ListAllMyBuckets only applies to S3 and no other AWS resource, "*" is shorthand for "arn:aws:s3:::*". In this case both statements are exactly the same.

Comment: John Hanley, Thanks. it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The actions in IAM policies have direct relation with AWS API. For example, the AWS S3 API has a ListAllMyBuckets call that serve to, surprise: List All Buckets of your account. There is no point in give permission to "List All Your Buckets" and at the same time do not allow list some of then.

The same happens with DescribeInstances API for EC2. If you need to create limitation in your policies, you must use Conditions. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_iam-condition-keys.html). But they are not available in all cases.

Comment: Thanks Gustavo Tavares. Do you mean the same as John Hanley? i.e. for ListAllMyBuckets, the meaning is very obvious, so instead of "arn:aws:s3:::", we can just use shorthand "*".

Comment: Sorry!! I just see your comment now. In the end of the day the effect will be the same, so you can use the shorthand in that case. Actually the actions and resources are always related. If you apply an action to a resource that does not accept it the AWS console will warn you. I confess that i do not know if you’ll get trouble using the cli or CloudFormation. I don’t remember to see the error except in console and I always use the CloudFormation to create policies. Maybe AWS just silent accept the invalid policy because it will probably do not make any harm because the default action is deny.